# If $p = f(w,a)$, what is $\mathbb{E}[w | p]$?

Tags: conditional-expectation

If $p = f(w,a)$, what is $\mathbb{E}[w | p]$?

Where $f$ is a continuous but unknown function, and $w$ and $a$ are correlated random variables.

Comment: This came up a couple days ago.  Search the site.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried but didn't even know what to search for.